# How would I go about adding a new key to a dictionary that corresponds to an already existing key

Tags: python, sqlite, dictionary

I am building a dictionary from a **SQLite** query that sums a certain value based on its preceding keys. What I am trying to do is insert a key value that exists outside of the **SQLite** query into the dictionary created from said query.

EX:

```
query_3 = cur.execute('''SELECT upc AS upc,
                               description AS desc,
                               department AS dept_no,
                               substr((datetime),1,4) AS year,
                               substr((datetime),6,2) AS month,
                               sum(total) AS spend,
                               count(distinct(substr((datetime),12,2) || register_no ||
                                       emp_no || trans_no)) as Transactions,
                               sum(CASE WHEN (trans_status = 'V' or trans_status = 'R') THEN -1 ELSE 1 END) as Items
                               FROM transactions
                               WHERE department != 0 and
                                    department != 15 and
                                    trans_status != 'M' and
                                    trans_status != 'C' and
                                    trans_status != 'J' and
                                   (trans_status = '' or 
                                    trans_status = ' ' or 
                                    trans_status = 'V' or 
                                    trans_status = 'R')
                      GROUP BY desc, year, month''')

d3 = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))))))))

for row in cur.fetchall() :
    upc, desc, dept_no, year, month, spend, transactions, items = row

d3[upc][desc][dept_no][year][month]['spend'] += spend
d3[upc][desc][dept_no][year][month]['trans'] += transactions
d3[upc][desc][dept_no][year][month]['items'] += items
```

What I want to do is add a `[dept_name]` key after the `[dept_no]` key in dict `d3`. I created a separate dictionary with the corresponding `dept_no / dept_names`, I just don't know how to merge them into my dict, `d3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, this will do it.

```
d3[upc][desc][dept_no]['dept_name'] = "Something"
```

You create a key in an existing dict by just assigning a value to it.

**Example:**

```
mydict = {'something': 1,'something2': 2}
print(mydict)
>>> {'something': 1, 'something2': 2} # print shows 2 values

mydict['something3'] = 3 # add a new key
print(mydict)
>>> {'something': 1, 'something3': 3, 'something2': 2} # now print shows 3 values, which confirms that we added a new key and value to the dict.
```

Comment: Would that work for inserting it into the middle of the dict? As you can see, `[dept_no]` is in the middle, and the value I'm intending to add would come right after that.

Comment: Dicts have levels/layers, that's why we need to put `[upc][desc][dept_no]` to store the new key at the new level. But dicts have no order/indexes (_unordered by definition_). Keys are stored wherever they are and it doesn't matter in which order because you access to them by calling the key name. Note that my `something3` key appeared at the middle.

Comment: Totally overlooked it being in the middle. That did it!